# Create a file with root access and make it executable?

Tags: executable, docky

I am having issues with Docky app and found this one and only solution online that could probably help.

http://www.linux-compatible.com/tutorial/docky-closes-after-waking-suspend-ubuntu
it also has a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sab2I-q6npc

I am new to Ubuntu, the instructions provided are very much unclear to me.
The video doesn't help as well.

I just need a simple instructions on what to click and how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the two files listed in your link.

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_docky
sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/20_docky
```

Make a file executable open Terminal, Crl-Alt-T

```
sudo chmod ugo+x /etc/pm/power.d/20_docky
sudo chmod ugo+x /etc/pm/power.d/20_docky
```

This command will make it executable for everyone.  u=user, o=owner, g=group.

Other options r=read w=write.  For complete information from Terminal enter

```
man chmod
```

Having created the file and changed to executable, copy the code blocks from your link and hopefully, all will go well.

To run the two scripts, the easiest way is the open the two files created in with gedit

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/20_docky
```

The copy the script from your link and paste into the open file.  Save the file and exit.

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/20_docky
```

Copy the text for this file from your link, save and exit.

Then reboot and see if it is working.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. That's not the same with how it was made in the video (link included). Will that do the same thing for me? Thanks again!

Comment: If I answered your question, please click the solution star.  Thanks.

Comment: @JyeRamirez It won't hurt to try and see if the solution works but giving the wrong file root privileges could be a security risk.

Comment: Okay. Imma try now. I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm just afraid of doing lot of unfamiliar things. I'll do it if it works @RCF-U14.04

Comment: Hi @RCF-U14.04, it didn't work. I guess what mentioned is to make an existing file executable? I'm trying to make one out of the script provided in the link.. Hope someone can help me here :(

chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_docky’: No such file or directory

Comment: I just updated the solution for you with complete file creation with pathnames as described in the link you provided.  Please read to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @JyeRamirez I took a look at the tutorial and have your answer below

Comment: Here's what I am getting: chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/pm/power.d/20_docky’: No such file or directory     @RCF-U14.04

Comment: @RCF-U14.04  
What he's doing in the video was:

vi /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_docky

Then it will show something, then paste the script, then I don't know what to click next.

Comment: Using vi is more difficult than gedit.  Look above I have included the complete set of steps for you.

Comment: @RCF-U14.04 I just rebooted. It worked for me. Thanks! You've been a big help!

Comment: What does the "20_" in the filename do as apposed to "10_" ?
Still learning scripts and am curious. Script worked great btw

Comment: @Rob - It's just the file name required in the link provided by the asking user.  Probably set up by the Docky app..